# Equation of motion of a system

Tags: function-construction, physics

I am studying the problem in [Vibration effects](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~wow/papers/vibration.pdf). I would like to obtain the simplified equation of motion in (2.7).

```
\[Lambda] =Sqrt[l^2 + a^2 (3 Cos[\[Phi]] - Sqrt[3] Sin[\[Phi]])];\[Lambda]ang = Simplify[\[Lambda] /. \[Phi] -> \[Theta] + 5/6 Pi]
```

and

```
h = Sqrt[ l^2 - 2 a^2 (1 - Cos[\[Phi]])]; hang = Simplify[h /. \[Phi] -> \[Theta] + 5/6 Pi]
```

Elastic energy in (2.3) can be written as:

```
U = 3/2 k (\[Lambda]ang - \[Lambda]n)^2
```

How can I write the Kinetic energy in (2.4)?
Moreover, How can I write the equations in (2.5) and (2.6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows:
Here are the definitions:

```
  \[Lambda][x_] := Sqrt[L^2 - 2 Sqrt[3] a^2*Cos[x]];
\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta]_] := 
 3/2 \[Kappa] (\[Lambda][\[Theta][t]] - \[Lambda]N)
\[CapitalDelta][t_] := 3*\[Gamma]*D[\[Lambda][\[Theta][t]], t]^2
h[x_] := Sqrt[L^2 - a^2*(2 + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x] + Sin[x])];
```

Now - the definition of the energy:

```
k[t_] := 3/2*m*a^2*\[Theta][t]^2 + 3/2*m*D[h[\[Theta][t]], t]^2;
k[t]
```

yielding:

[image]

Now let us just substitute the above definitions into the formula (2.6):

```
(\[Theta]''[t]*D[k[t], \[Theta]'[t]] + \[Theta]'[t]*
  D[k[t], \[Theta][t]]) + \[Theta]'[t]*
D[\[CapitalPhi][\[Theta][t]], \[Theta][t]] + \[CapitalDelta][
t] == 0 // Simplify
```

this gives the following heavy formula:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: In your definitions, I found some discrepancies: \[CapitalPhi][\[Theta]_] := 
 3/2 \[Kappa] (\[Lambda][\[Theta][t]] - \[Lambda]N)^2...is it correct?

Comment: Considering (2.4), the definition of the energy should be: k[t_] := 3/2*m*a^2*D[\[Theta][t], t]^2 + 3/2*m*D[h[\[Theta][t]], t]^2...is it correct?

Comment: If you find any errors - correct them. I gave you an idea. The rest is up to you.